# Density of water at a given temperature and pressure

Tags: chemistry, wolfram-alpha-queries

In `Wolfram|Alpha` if I write:

```
density water at 500°C and 100 atm
```

instantly I read:

> 30.92 kg/m^3  (kilograms per cubic meter)

and the same is true for many other pairs of values.

Is there any way to do the same in offline Mathematica?

I would love to know the formulation to which it refers, I have been looking in Google for a day and reading papers but so far I have not found any article that has such high values!

Thanks.

Comment: I thought only gas density depends on temp. and pressure, but water is not a gas? But you can ask in the Physics form. if you are using Mathematic offline, then Mathematica can't call Wolfram Alpha. need to have internet access.

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/281066252_Understanding_on_thermodynamic_properties_of_van_der_Waals_equation_of_state_with_the_use_of_Mathematica  ... and when can do all this for water, you will be able to get the answer offline. More info: https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/jccjie/4/0/4_2017-0042/_html/-char/en cc: @Nasser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Free-form input (i.e. `Ctrl` + `=`) of your query returns:

```
ThermodynamicData["Water", "Density", {"Temperature" -> 
   Quantity[500, "DegreesCelsius"], 
  "Pressure" -> Quantity[100, "Atmospheres"]}]
```

Some digging around for the source for `ThermodynamicData` yields: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/note/ThermodynamicDataSourceInformation.html, so I would start by looking at the [`NIST Reference Fluid Thermodynamic and Transport Properties Database (REFPROP)`](https://www.nist.gov/srd/refprop).

Comment: This does not work when one is "offline" which is what OP said they wanted. This makes a call to Wolfram server. It is basically like calling Wolfram alpha from inside Mathematica as alternative method to obtain the answer.

Comment: Yes, of-course. Was trying to give the OP a reference in answer to their question: `I would love to know the formulation to which it refers`

Comment: I see. I thought this was the answer to `Is there any way to do the same in offline Mathematica?`. no problem.

Comment: I have not tested this and have no proof that the following is entirely correct, but I think all the Data-functions work like this: when first called, they download the dataset that is needed. After that (even in the next mathematica session) the downloaded data is used locally so the `ThermodynamicData` function will work locally. It still will try to connect to WRI servers to look for updates, but if that doesn't work it will use the downloaded dataset. Maybe that is good enough for your definition of "local"?